# Pygame cursor blitting

Tags: python, pygame, cursor, mouse

I am currently working on a RPG game right now.And i need to blit a cool looking cursor for it but my actual cursor is blitted on the new cursor.
How can i fix that?

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
newcursor = "glove3.png"
display = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0, 32)
glovecursor = pygame.image.load(newcursor).convert_alpha()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    display.fill((0,0,0))
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= glovecursor.get_width()/7
    y -= glovecursor.get_height()/19
    display.blit(glovecursor,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a sprite with its own image/surface and in its update function, just set its position to the current position of the cursor.

`self.pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

But the above `set_cursor()` and `pygame.cursors` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`pygame.cursors`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html). Also [`pygame.mouse.set_cursor`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_cursor).

Basically, you use `pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*cursor)` where `cursor` contains various data about the cursor in this format: `(size, hotspot, xormasks, andmasks)`